# "TIFF file is missing a required tag StripOffsets" - ошибка при работе с классом GeotiffReader

Tags: java

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема - при работе с некоторыми .tiff при попытке получить `DataRaster[]` с использованием метода `readDataRaster()` (класс `GeotiffReader` библиотеки NASA WorldWind) выдается исключение:

> ERROR j.l.Throwable - java.io.IOException: TIFF file is missing a
>   required tagStripOffsets

Вот сам код, который работает с некоторыми .tiff:

```
private GeotiffReader reader;
private ByteBufferRaster raster;
...
reader = new GeotiffReader(file);
listDataRaster.add(reader.readDataRaster());
...
DataRaster[] dataRaster = listDataRaster.get(iter);
raster = (ByteBufferRaster)dataRaster[0];
...
raster.setDoubleAtPosition(y, x, value);
```

Ошибка возникает в следующей строке:

```
listDataRaster.add(reader.readDataRaster());
```

Метод пытается вернуть `DataRaster[]` и выдает ошибку.

Моя задача - взять у .tiff-а `ByteBufferRaster`, а затем использовать `setDoubleAtPosition`, чтобы внести изменения в сетку после некоторых вычислений и переписать измененный .tiff.

Как исправить эту ошибку? А если никак, есть ли другие способы выполнить мою задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, задачу смог решить вот таким путем через ExtendedGDALDataRaster

```
DataRasterReaderFactory readerFactory = (DataRasterReaderFactory) WorldWind
                .createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.DATA_RASTER_READER_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME);
DataRasterReader dataRasterReader;
DataRaster[] dataRasters = null;
...
dataRasterReader = readerFactory.findReaderFor(file, null);
dataRasters = dataRasterReader.read(file, null);
...
rasterGdal = (ExtendedGDALDataRaster) dataRasters[0];

ElevationModel elevationModelFromGlobe = GLOBE.getElevationModel(); 
Sector boundingSector = rasterGdal.getSector();
int[] heightAndWidth = new int[2];  

//Метод для создания пустого сектора по аналогии с текущим          
recalculationHeightAndWidth (boundingSector, elevationModelFromGlobe, heightAndWidth);

//Метод для создания параметров по умолчанию для сектора
AVList params = getParams(boundingSector, heightAndWidth[1], heightAndWidth[0]);
raster = (ByteBufferRaster) ByteBufferRaster.createGeoreferencedRaster(params);

Dataset dataset = rasterGdal.getBestSuitedDataset(heightAndWidth[1], heightAndWidth[0], rasterGdal.getSector());
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1);
```

И затем для можно доставать значение высоты любой точки из *.tiff и менять его на свое усмотрение (оно будет лежать в data)

```
float[] data = new float[1];
band.ReadRaster(x, y, 1, 1, band.getDataType(), data);
```